# How to convert regexp_substr(Oracle) to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a data table which has a column as Acctno what is expected shows in separate column

```
|Acctno                | expected_output|
|ABC:BKS:1023049101    | 1023049101     |
|ABC:UWR:19048234582   | 19048234582    |
|ABC:UEW:1039481843    | 1039481843     |
```

I know in Oracle SQL which I used the below

```
select regexp_substr(acctno,'[^:]',1,3) as expected_output
from temp_mytable
```

but in Microsoft SQL Server I am getting an error that `regexp_substr` is not a built in function

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: There are loads of resources out there about this, you need to do some research, have a go, and post a question when stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `PATINDEX` with `SUBSTRING` here:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING(acctno, PATINDEX('%:[0-9]%', acctno) + 1, LEN(acctno)) AS expected_output
FROM temp_mytable;
```

### Demo

Note that this answer assumes that the third component would always start with a digit, and that the first two components would not have any digits.  If this were not true, then we would have to do more work.

Answer (score 0):

Just another option if the desired value is the last portion of the string and there are not more than 4 segments.

```
Select * 
      ,NewValue = parsename(replace(Acctno,':','.'),1)
 from YourTable
```